# Translation of 'thinking' and 'continuously' into Latin (as used in these phrases)

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation

I'm looking for the most "correct" translations of the following related phrases into Latin:

(1) 'Thinking on it continuously'
(2) 'Thinking continuously'
(3) 'By thinking on it continuously'

Google Translate informs me that 'cogitatione continue' is appropriate for 'thinking continuously' but I'm unsure as to the use of either word in this case.

Comment: Can you tell us some more context? That might help us understand what distinctions you have in mind among those phrases.

Comment: Sure. Q: What have you been doing? A: Thinking continuously. Q: How did you come to this solution? A: By thinking on the problem continuously. Hopefully that clarifies what is denoted by 'thinking' and 'continuously'.

Comment: That definitely helps. Could you tell us some more context, like what leads you to ask the question? Are you trying to answer a theoretical question about linguistics, compose a tattoo, write dialogue for a character in a novel, write a sign for your office door, …? (BTW, Google Translate is probably wrong for all of those.)